# Алгоритмы оценки цикломатической сложности в OpenCover и в Visual Studio

Tags: алгоритм, visual-studio-2013

При оценке сложности работы алгоритма *OpenCover* и *VS* выдают разные результаты.

Как оценивает *OpenCover* и как *VS*?

На следующем примере для OpenCover результат 2 для студии 3:

```
public class ForTests
{
    delegate int del(int i, int p);
    public void Testing(int a, int b)
    {
        del myDelegate = (x, y) => y * x;
        int j = myDelegate(5, 5);
    }
}
```

На таких конструкциях тоже результаты отличаются и очень на много:

```
using (SqlCommand sqlc = SqlHelper.GetCommandExecuteSql ( sql запрос) {}
```

Comment: приведите пример кода, на котором получается разный результат. вместе с самим результатом для обеих систем.

Answer (score 1):

Идея цикломатической сложности появилась очень давно, когда что было написано в коде - то и выполнялось. И она просто не совместима с "синтаксическим сахаром" вроде лямбд.

Проблема в том, что лямбды (и в виде анонимных делегатов, и в виде деревьев выражений) - это не часть кода метода. И как считать их сложность - кто его знает. Например:

```
static void SomeMethod()
{ 
    Action a = () =>
    {
        if (c > b)
        {

        }
    };
}
```

Согласно определению, цикломатическая сложность этого метода - 1. В нем нет ветвлений. `if` внутри делегата не выполняется. `if` вообще не имеет отношения к `SomeMethod`. Но утилиты насчитают 3. А может быть и 4.

Дополняет эту проблему генерация кода компилятором. Скромный код

```
static void SomeMethod2()
{
    Action a = () => { };
}
```

При компиляции разворачивается в что-то вроде

```
private static void SomeMethod()
{
  Action action = Program.<>c.<>9__1_0 ?? (Program.<>c.<>9__1_0 = new Action((object) Program.<>c.<>9, __methodptr(<SomeMethod>b__1_0)));
}

[CompilerGenerated]
[Serializable]
private sealed class <>c
{
  public static readonly Program.<>c <>9;
  public static Action <>9__1_0;

  static <>c()
  {
    Program.<>c.<>9 = new Program.<>c();
  }

  public <>c()
  {
    base..ctor();
  }

  internal void <SomeMethod>b__1_0()
  {
  }
}
```

И сложность тут наверное 3 - из-за `??` (его надо считать? или не надо - в исходном коде ничего такого нет?) и самого тела метода (оно же считается отдельным путем? или не считается?).

То же самое с `using` - это неявный `try`/`finally`. Утилита может считать блок `try` ветвлением. А может и не считать.

Из-за таких неоднозначностей и получается разбежка в показателях. Причем чем сложнее метод - тем разница между утилитами, и даже между двумя версиями одной и той же утилиты, будет значительнее.

Comment: а для LINQ выражений ЦС тоже не считается. Или существует правило оценки?

Comment: @Victor Считается, но ситуация та же - на усмотрение разработчика утилиты. ЦС это понятие из мира императивного программирования. А LINQ и вообще SQL-подобный синтаксис - это декларативное программирование, В нем описывается что надо получить. А не как это получить. И ЦС, завязанная на "как" (граф потока управления), просто не применима.